# Create diagonal matrix without using MATLAB built-in functions

Tags: matlab, diagonal

I know the answer to this question as shown below.

```
function a = reverse_diag(n)
    b = zeros(n);
    b(1:n+1:end) = 1;
    a(1:n, n:-1:1) = b(1:n, 1:n);
end
```

But why does it look like that? What does this mean?

```
b(1:n+1:end) = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to recall seeing something similar to this in MATLAB answers very recently, hence I will be brief.

MATLAB arrays can be indexed in 2 relevant ways:

1. Like `A(x,y)` using the actual coordinates in the matrix.
2. Like `A(index)`, no matter how many dimensions the matrix `A` actually has. This is called linear indexing and will go through the matrix column by column. So for a 10x10 matrix, `A(11)` is actually `A(2,1)`.

Read up on [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) and [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to get a sense of how these work. You should now be able to figure out why that line works.

Comment: Thanks mate! Got it now